# Google plus sign in error on android(Error signing in the specified Account...)

Tags: android, google-plus

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE = 8;
private static final int SHARE_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE = 9;
private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE = 11;

// layout for showing user control buttons
private LinearLayout userOptionsLayout;
// layout for showing signed in user info
private LinearLayout userInfoLayout;

private ImageView userProfilePic;
private TextView userName;
private TextView userEmail;
private TextView userLocation;
private TextView userTagLine;
private TextView userAboutMe;
private TextView userBirthday;

Button signOutButton;
Button userInfoButton;
Button sharePostButton;
Button shareMediaButton;
Button revokeAccessButton;

// For communicating with Google APIs
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private boolean mSignInClicked;
private boolean mIntentInProgress;
// contains all possible error codes for when a client fails to connect to
// Google Play services
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    signOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
    signOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    userInfoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_userinfo_button);
    userInfoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    sharePostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_post_button);
    sharePostButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    shareMediaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_media_button);
    shareMediaButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    revokeAccessButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.revoke_access_button);
    revokeAccessButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.user_options_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    userOptionsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_options_layout);
    userInfoLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_info_layout);

    userProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_pic);
    userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    userEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_email);
    userLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_location);

    // Initializing google plus api client
    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleAPIClient();
}

/**
 * API to return GoogleApiClient Make sure to create new after revoking
 * access or for first time sign in
 *
 * @return
 */
private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleAPIClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // make sure to initiate connection
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // disconnect api if it is connected
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

/**
 * Handle Button onCLick Events based upon their view ID
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            processSignIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            processSignOut();
            break;
        case R.id.show_userinfo_button:
            userOptionsLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            userInfoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.share_post_button:
            processSharePost();
            break;
        case R.id.share_media_button:
            processShareMedia();
            break;
        case R.id.revoke_access_button:
            processRevokeRequest();
            break;
        case R.id.user_options_button:
            userInfoLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            userOptionsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }

}

/**
 * API to update layout views based upon user signed in status
 *
 * @param isUserSignedIn
 */
private void processUIUpdate(boolean isUserSignedIn) {
    if (isUserSignedIn) {
        signOutButton.setEnabled(true);
        userInfoButton.setEnabled(true);
        sharePostButton.setEnabled(true);
        shareMediaButton.setEnabled(true);
        revokeAccessButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        signOutButton.setEnabled(false);
        userInfoButton.setEnabled(false);
        sharePostButton.setEnabled(false);
        shareMediaButton.setEnabled(false);
        revokeAccessButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Handle results for your startActivityForResult() calls. Use requestCode
 * to differentiate.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // If picking media is success, create share post using
        // PlusShare.Builder
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            String mime = cr.getType(selectedImage);

            PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
            share.setText("Hello from AndroidSRC.net");
            share.addStream(selectedImage);
            share.setType(mime);
            startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(),
                    SHARE_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * API to revoke granted access After revoke user will be asked to grant
 * permission on next sign in
 */
private void processRevokeRequest() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Result result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User permissions revoked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleAPIClient();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                processUIUpdate(false);
            }
        });

    }

}

/**
 * API to process media post request start activity with MIME type as video
 * and image
 */
private void processShareMedia() {
    Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPicker.setType("video/*, image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPicker, PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE);

}

/**
 * API to process post share request Use PlusShare.Builder to create share
 * post.
 */
private void processSharePost() {
    // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this).setType("text/plain")
            .setText("Google+ Demo http://androidsrc.net")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://androidsrc.net")).getIntent();

    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);

}

/**
 * API to handle sign out of user
 */
private void processSignOut() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        processUIUpdate(false);
    }

}

/**
 * API to handler sign in of user If error occurs while connecting process
 * it in processSignInError() api
 */
private void processSignIn() {

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        processSignInError();
        mSignInClicked = true;
    }

}

/**
 * API to process sign in error Handle error based on ConnectionResult
 */
private void processSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult != null && mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Callback for GoogleApiClient connection failure
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE).show();
        return;
    }
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            processSignInError();
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Callback for GoogleApiClient connection success
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed In Successfully",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    processUserInfoAndUpdateUI();

    processUIUpdate(true);

}

/**
 * Callback for suspension of current connection
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

/**
 * API to update signed in user information
 */
private void processUserInfoAndUpdateUI() {
    Person signedInUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (signedInUser != null) {

        if (signedInUser.hasDisplayName()) {
            String userName = signedInUser.getDisplayName();
            this.userName.setText("Name: " + userName);
        }

        if (signedInUser.hasTagline()) {
            String tagLine = signedInUser.getTagline();
            this.userTagLine.setText("TagLine: " + tagLine);
            this.userTagLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (signedInUser.hasAboutMe()) {
            String aboutMe = signedInUser.getAboutMe();
            this.userAboutMe.setText("About Me: " + aboutMe);
            this.userAboutMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (signedInUser.hasBirthday()) {
            String birthday = signedInUser.getBirthday();
            this.userBirthday.setText("DOB " + birthday);
            this.userBirthday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (signedInUser.hasCurrentLocation()) {
            String userLocation = signedInUser.getCurrentLocation();
            this.userLocation.setText("Location: " + userLocation);
            this.userLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        String userEmail = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        this.userEmail.setText("Email: " + userEmail);

        if (signedInUser.hasImage()) {
            String userProfilePicUrl = signedInUser.getImage().getUrl();
            // default size is 50x50 in pixels.changes it to desired size
            int profilePicRequestSize = 250;

            userProfilePicUrl = userProfilePicUrl.substring(0,
                    userProfilePicUrl.length() - 2) + profilePicRequestSize;
            new UpdateProfilePicTask(userProfilePic)
                    .execute(userProfilePicUrl);
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Background task to download user profile picture
 *
 * @author androidsrc.net
 *
 */
private class UpdateProfilePicTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    WeakReference profileView;

    public UpdateProfilePicTask(ImageView img) {
        profileView = new WeakReference(img);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap profilePic = null;
        try {
            URL downloadURL = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL
                    .openConnection();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200)
                throw new Exception("Error in connection");
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            profilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return profilePic;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (result != null && profileView != null) {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) profileView.get();
            if (view != null)
                view.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

}`
```

I am trying to integrate google plus sign-in on my android app. While running, everything works perfectly until I need to choose an account. After choosing an account, it shows "Error signing in the specified account. Please choose a different account". How do I fix this error?

Comment: have u configured the scopes correctly?

Comment: Post your error with some code.

Comment: @GrIsHu-I attached it with the code,please have a look

Comment: are you using an emulator or an actual device ?

Comment: Have you properly configured your application on google console?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie--I am running on my device actually...

Comment: @GrIsHu-Ya checked,all fine